# WebResources in an ASP.NET website

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, sitefinity

I'm developing a website using SiteFinity in Visual Studio 2008. This is a web site project rather than a web application project.

During development I am finding myself developing lots and lots of user controls. The problem with this is that each user control needs to use some javascript and css. Now i can either include the css/js for every single control in a couple of global css/js files, or I have started reading today about Web Resources.

Strangely, I cant seem to find any information that shows me, how to achieve this, and whether it has to be a compiled file rather than just creating resources which can be accessed from my user controls.

Can anyone provide a brief overview, or point me in the right direction to one?

Thanks in advance
higgsy

Comment: Hey Higgsy, what is the benefit you're looking for from embedded resources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't create embedded resources in a Web Site Project.

You can create embedded resources in a Web Application Project.

[image]

This **Build Action** property will be missing in a Web Site Project.  If you're using a Web Site Project, you can create a new Class project (new assembly), which will enable you to use Embedded Resources.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registerclientscriptresource.aspx)'s how to add script resources to a page. The resource should be in a compiled assembly, its build action should be set to "Embedded Resource" (through right click -> properties), and it should be registered as a web resource in the assembly's AssemblyInfo.cs file.

If we assume you only need to do this for client-side code and not other types of web resources, and if you are developing [script controls](http://magmainteractive.net/tutorials/post/Building-ASPNET-35-AJAX-Script-Controls.aspx) (with their client side compontents), this could be directly done in the implementation of [GetScriptReferences](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.iscriptcontrol.getscriptreferences.aspx) method.